# Merge folders that only contains one folder

Tags: windows-7

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
(root) – Folder1  – Folder2  – file3
                             – file4
                             – file5
                                 ︙
       – Folder11 – Folder12 – file13
                             – file14
                             – file15
                                 ︙
            ︙
```

I.e., Folder1, Folder11, Folder21, … each contain only a single subdirectory.
These subdirectories (Folder2, Folder12, Folder22, …) serve no purpose.
I would like to move file3, file4, file5, …, into Folder1, and then delete the empty Folder2.  And then repeat throughout the tree; e.g.,

```
(root) – Folder1  – file3
                  – file4
                  – file5
                      ︙
       – Folder11 – file13
                  – file14
                  – file15
                      ︙
            ︙
```

Doing this manually is impractical because I have hundreds or thousands of folders like this.
I already know "Remove empty directory" which is really great for deleting empty folders , but it's not the same.

How would I merge these easily in a Windows 7 system?

Comment: At Superuser we don't do software recommendation, unless it is relevant to solving a concrete problem. As I see it, it is slightly vague: how are every folders organized? Is there something stopping you from selecting all folders and moving them to the base folder?. I also suggest you take some time to read the [about] page, to understand how the StackExchange Network works differently than other sites.

Comment: @Gamnamno: I guessed what you meant. If I guessed wrong, [edit] the question to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CMD (I have removed the blank from "folder 1" so as to simplify the example, by removing the need for quotes.):-

```
c:
cd \folder1
for /r %f in (*) do move /-y %f \folder1\
for /d %f in (*) do rd /s /q %f
```

It would be safer to create a new destination folder and move the files there: once you were sure that all the files had been moved (with **dir /s**), delete *\folder1* (with **rd /s**) and rename (using **move**) the new folder back to *\folder1*:-

```
c:
md \newfolder1
cd \folder1
for /r %f in (*) do move /-y %f \newfolder1\
dir /s
rem If the previous command shows no files then proceed with:-
cd \
rd /s /q \folder1
move \newfolder1 \folder1
```

Note that there will be prompts if names are duplicated in different subdirectories (I included **/-y** in the **move** command in case you ever put the commands into a batch file).

Comment: Hi,
I tried this but when I type this line : for /r %f in (*) do move /-y %f \folder1\ , I get incorrect syntax errors, my folders being in the desktop and properly named folder1, folder2, etc...

Comment: If you were in a batch file, you should have doubled the percent signs as in `for /r %%f in (*) do move /-y %%f \newfolder1\ `.